# Combine $and and $or conditions in a MongoDB query where document has embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with many documents;

[image]

I would like to return all documents where individuals are (older than 30 AND less than 37 years old), OR live in Italy.

My attempt

```
db.getCollection('persons')
                          .find(                                
                                    $or:[
                                            {$and: [
                                                        {age:{$gte:30}},
                                                        {age:{$lt:37}}
                                                   ],
                                            {"company.location.country": "Italy"}
                                       ]
                                )
```

Which yields an error

[image]

Comment: what's your question? This query seems correct.

Comment: I get Unexpected Token

Comment: Try this `db.getCollection('persons').find({
  $or: [
    {
      $and: [
        {
          age: {
            $gte: 30
          }
        },
        {
          age: {
            $lt: 37
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "company.location.country": "Italy"
    }
  ]
})`

Comment: Thank @Anthony Winzlet, that works. I'm new to MongoDB, so still sorting my brackets and braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be simplified to

```
{
  $or: [
    { age: { $lt: 37, $gte: 30 } },
    { "company.localtion.country": "Italy" }
  ]
}
```